# python return value meet the error.help me

Tags: python

I am sorry i meet the akward problem in my python program. First of all I am newbie here and I am a Chinese student. Please forgive my poor English. I will try my best to express the problem clearly.

the Error Code is Here:

```
        def __find__(self,node,value):
            if value<node.v:
                self.__find__(node.l,value)
            elif value>node.v:
                self.__find__(node.r,value)
            elif value==node.v:
                return node.obj

        def Find(self,value):
            obj=self.__find__(self.r,value)
            print obj
            return obj
```

when I print the node.obj in **find** function it works well but when I print the obj in  Find function, it return None.
This question is bothering me all day. if someone could solve it, it will be very  appreciated.

thanks guy

Complete code here:i just write the BTS tree:

```
    ####class####

    class BSTtreeNode:
        def __init__(self,lnode=None,rnode=None,parent=None,value=None,obj=None):
            self.l=lnode
            self.r=rnode
            self.p=parent
            self.v=value
            self.obj=obj


    class BSTree:
        def __init__(self,RootNode=None):
            self.r=RootNode
        def Insert(self,value,obj):
            self.__insert__(self.r,value,obj)
        def __insert__(self,node,value,obj):
            if value<=node.v:
                if node.l==None:
                    localnode=BSTtreeNode(lnode=None,rnode=None,parent=node,value=value,obj=obj)
                    node.l=localnode
                elif node.l!=None:
                    self.__insert__(node.l,value,obj)
            if value>node.v:
                if node.r==None:
                    localnode=BSTtreeNode(lnode=None,rnode=None,parent=node,value=value,obj=obj)
                    node.r=localnode
                elif node.r!=None:
                    self.__insert__(node.r,value,obj)

        def __find__(self,node,value):
            if value<node.v:
                self.__find__(node.l,value)
            elif value>node.v:
                self.__find__(node.r,value)
            elif value==node.v:
                return node.obj

        def Find(self,value):
            obj=self.__find__(self.r,value)
            print obj
            return obj
        def Print(self):
                self.__printTree__(self.r)  

        def __printTree__(self,node):
                if node.l==None and node.r==None:
                    print node.v,node.obj
                    return 
                elif node.r != None:
                    self.__printTree__(node.r)
                elif node.l !=None:
                    self.__printTree__(node.l)
                print node.v,node.obj


    def main():
        mNode=BSTtreeNode(value=10,obj="first")
        bstree=BSTree(RootNode=mNode)
        bstree.Insert(value=20,obj="second")
        bstree.Insert(30,obj="second")
        bstree.Print()
        bstree.Find(value=20)

    if __name__ =="__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing some `return`s in your `__find__` function. Change both occurrences of `self.__find__(...)` to `return self.__find__(...)`.

```
def __find__(self, node, value):
    if value < node.v:
        return self.__find__(node.l, value)
    elif value > node.v:
        return self.__find__(node.r, value)
    elif value == node.v:
        print node.obj
        return node.obj

def Find(self, value):
    obj = self.__find__(self.r, value)
    print obj
    return obj
```

You call the function again, but you don't return the value. As you don't explicitly return a value, `None` is implicitly returned.

Comment: i am sorry that i get less than 15 repution.and could't vote to you

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code to this:

```
def __find__(self,node,value):
    if value<node.v:
        return self.__find__(node.l,value)
    elif value>node.v:
        return self.__find__(node.r,value)
    elif value==node.v:
        return node.obj
```